# How to sort a <list> of class in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have a list of a class like this :

```
 public class CityCodeInfo
 {
    public string CityName;
    public string Province;
    public string Code; 
  }

  List<CityCodeInfo> lstCityt = new List<CityCodeInfo>();
```

How can i sort this list by any of its variables (cityname, province and code)

i've tried this code:

```
  lstCityt.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.CityName, y.CityName));
```

but it doesn't work...

Any Idea?!

Comment: "it doesn't work" is very vague. What happens when you try? Please give a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. (This has nothing to do with ASP.NET, either.)

Comment: It really looks like the above code will work. `Sort` will only sort the items already in the list, not change the way future items are added. So you can only sort after you've populated your list. Otherwise, use a sorted collection instead of `List<>`.

Comment: Are you looking for **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx**??

Comment: i do sort after populating the list but it doesn't sort. there is not a huge code just a list of class that i show it by repeater in a web page. but i want it ordered.

Comment: Maybe the "consumer" (web page) does not notice the the `List<>` has changed? It might need to re-read, or wait to read until after your sorting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use LINQ for it.

**Ascending Order**

```
var result = lstCityt.OrderBy(C=> C.CityName).ThenBy(C=> C.Province).ThenBy(C=> C.Code);
```

**Descending Order**

```
var result = lstCityt.OrderByDescending(C=> C.CityName).ThenByDescending(C=> C.Province).ThenByDescending(C=> C.Code);
```

**Both**

```
var result = lstCityt.OrderBy(C=> C.CityName).ThenByDescending(C=> C.Province).ThenByDescending(C=> C.Code);
```

Comment: Why use LINQ when `List<>.Sort` is faster, and is what the Original Poster asks for? Your solution does not alter the original `List<>`, only gives a new `IEnumerable<>` with the sorted order.

Comment: i test u'r code, but nothing happen. no error, no sorting list. how to work with IEnumerable<>?!

Comment: @maryammohammadi result variable contains your sorted data and you can convert this result IEnumerable<> in to List via ToList() method.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, in terms to use Sort method the class must implement IComparable or IComparable<T> interface and also write the delegates to sort the elements of list, so i think this would be the simplest solution. For your concern find [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38917/How-To-Sort-Generic-List) article to use sort method with list

Comment: The Original Poster uses an overload of `Sort` that takes a `Comparison<CityCodeInfo>` delegate as an argument. Therefore that delegate will be used for the sorting, and in that case `CityCodeInfo` does not need to implement `IComparable`.

Comment: @ Kundan Singh Chouhan Thank u very much. it works well. i do appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

What you already have is already complete and correct:

```
lstCityt.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.CityName, y.CityName));
```

That indeed sorts a list of a class. It sounds like you are seeing some *secondary* issue to do with the repeater, but you have not provided context for that. The main thing I'd look at is timing, i.e. whether you binding *before* or *after* sorting the list.